# hadoop for spark: Increase number of partitions

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I've getting an error each time I tried to load a huge elasticsearch index using the hadoop-2.6.0-for-spark connector.

Am running spark on Yarn.

```
15/09/30 17:57:21 ERROR shuffle.OneForOneBlockFetcher: Failed while starting block fetches
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:836)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetLocal(BlockManager.scala:512)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getBlockData(BlockManager.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:57)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.receive(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:114)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:87)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:101)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:162)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:103)
at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
```

So far, the solution I see is to increase the number of partions but how do I do freaking do that using hadoop-2.6.0-for-spark.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue by increasing the executor memory, seems when trying to cache the RDD to disk throws the exception due to the size of the block being cached to disk.